# ASP.NET CS1061 missing definition error inside of Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, aspwizard

Here is the error I get on **Line 86**

> CS1061: 'ASP.tabs_profile_vieweditprofile_aspx' does not contain a
> definition for 'Wizard1_FinishButtonClick' and no extension method
> 'Wizard1_FinishButtonClick' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ASP.tabs_profile_vieweditprofile_aspx' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 84: </asp:Content>
Line 85: <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
Line 86:     <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" Height="511px" 
Line 87:     StartNextButtonText="Edit Info" DisplaySideBar="False" 
Line 88:         FinishCompleteButtonText="Save"
```

And I do have the method for my button in the CS class. Any suggestions?!?

```
protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
 
}
```

Source code.

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0" Height="511px" 
StartNextButtonText="Edit Info" DisplaySideBar="False" 
    FinishCompleteButtonText="Save" 
    style="text-align: center; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 95px; width: 670px;" 
    onfinishbuttonclick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .ascx and .ascx.cs Namespaces won't be matching - it's a popular error. Make sure your Inherits namespace matches the one in the .cs file. That'll likely be the issue here.